# Cairo-Dock: Is it possible to start/show/hide apps by <Super>+[1-9]

Tags: 12.10, cairo-dock

I have a cairo-dock related question
I would like to know if it's possible to start Apps and show/hide their windows by pressing SUPER + [1-9]

For example: I have my cairo-dock panel and the 1st starter is google-chrome and the 2nd is nautilus, then i would like to start google-chrome by pressing SUPER + 1 and nautilus by pressing SUPER + 2.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can !
Enable the "Remote-control" applet, the default shortkey is ctrl+F9 but you can assign anything to it (especially if it's already used by another app).
Then press the shortkey, and press a number (or use the arrows to navigate in the dock) :)

PS: our forum is here for any question: http://glx-dock.org/bg_forumlist.php

Comment: I am on lubuntu, and I want the app launcher typing part to work a little bit like unity..  currently, i am using dmenu linked to a shortcut.   How to do this for cairo.  The first button on the left is a typing launcher.  I want that to get activated by mapping a super key or something. (I can do that in lubuntu).  I need to know the command to give the shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is implemented in Cairo Dock.  You can do it with CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm), under "commands".  Enter the command for launching the app in the "commands" tab, then the keystroke shortcut on the "key bindings" tab.  Note that this will not do everything you want, (e.g., it will not check to see if the app is running, and if so, either minimize or maximize as appropriate).

Comment: Thank you. I also found out in the meanwhile that it's not possible...